# How can I save the job result to a file?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-agent, logging

I created a job in SQL Server. This job runs the following statement at regular intervals:

```
Select NationalIDNumber from HumanResources.Employee where BusinessEntityID = '1'
```

I want to save the result of this query to a txt file. I clicked **Advanced** on the Step tab for the job I created. I wrote the path there, but when the job was run, no records were added to the txt file.

What else should I do to add the job result to txt?

Advanced Tab : Output File --> `D:\Data2\JobOutput.txt`

Comment: Welcome, i would suggest that you take a look on [dba.se] that are specialist about database management imho. iflagged forthis reason the question for movement, that you have specialist around you ;-)

Comment: Are you looking for the output file on the D: drive of your local PC, or on the D: drive of the server? When referred to in a SQL Agent job, it'll be the D: drive of the server. (That distinction trips me up from time to time.)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to share my solution for those who encounter the same problem.

When the job ran, no record was added to the relevant path. When I looked at the Properties section of the SQL Server Agent service, I saw which user started the service. This user who starts the service must have access to the path I provided in the Output File section. I added the user who started the service from the Security tab to have access to the D disk and the Data2 folder.

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You could createa job step with an type of ***CMDExec*** and use ***sqlcmd*** to run the query to the file in the output folder.

[image: Image of SSMS Job Step Creation Screen]

```
  sqlcmd -S <Servername> -E -Q "<Your Query>" -o "C:\<somepath>\outputfile.txt"
```

- If the file is not created, check the job history for errors.
- Ensure the path to the file is correct and accessible by SQL Server Agent